# Can't load load Google Chrome extension on Linux because folder begins with a dot (.)

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am using Google Chrome on Linux and am in the Extensions Developer Mode.

I want to load an unpacked extension and Chrome is asking me via a file dialog to open the extension folder. Unfortunately all of the Chrome extensions are located in Linux in a folder called ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/extensions. Since the config folder starts with a dot "." the Chrome file dialog is not showing that folder.

How can I open the unpacked extension?

Comment: Press `Ctrl H` while browsing for the file

Comment: @EugenRieck That worked. Would you like to make that an answer?

Comment: OK, I did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux file managers typically hide "dotfiles", i.e. files and folders starting with a `.`. THis functionallity can normally be enabled and disabled on demand by press ing `Ctrl-H` or using a menu option.

Since the file manager component is typically used when showing the "open file" dialog, the same shortcut can be used there. N.b. an exception: JavaX-Programs will typically no react to `Ctrl-H`

Comment: It's not just file managers. I believe this is a POSIX convention.

Comment: POSIX says nothing about file open dialogs